# passing an element object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know Im asking a simple question, but could you please let me know how I can pass the element object to a function:

Thanks

```
    function progress(percent, element) {
        var progressBarWidth = percent * element.width() / 100;
        // With labels:
        element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");


    }

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        progress(55,"#percentage");

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/RfYsL/404/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass like

```
progress(55,$("#percentage"));
```

and treat element paramter in progress like a jquery object like you do now.